# Lebesgue differentiation theorem implies Lebesgue density.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am asked to prove that for every $ E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ there exists some cube $Q$ such that $$m(E \cap Q) \ge (1 - \epsilon) m (Q)$$

I am fairly confident I know how to complete this problem. However, the problem statement is asking me to complete is using the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (which I wouldn't use explicitly).

Anywas, my question is, how does $$\lim_{m(B) \to 0, \hspace{1mm} x \in m(B)} \int_{B} f(y) dy = f(x)$$

where $m(B)$ is the measure of a ball containing $x$.

imply that $$m(B \cap E) \ge (1- \epsilon)m(B)?$$

I think it has to do with the characteristic function but I would just like to see this done in detail.

Comment: Your formulation of Lebesgues differentiation theorem is not correct. Review the statement. This will probably help you see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your statement is :

> $$\lim_{m(B) \to 0, \hspace{1mm} x \in B} \frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B}
>  f(y) dy = f(x).$$

Put $f(y)=\chi_{E}$ which is indicator function on $E$. Then 
$$
\lim_{m(B)\rightarrow0}\frac{m(E\cap B)}{m(B)}=1.
$$

Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a ball $B$ such that $1-\frac{m(E\cap B)}{m(B)}\leq\epsilon$.
Then you can get what you want to get.